# IE8 Developer Tools Pin will not work

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

IE8 Developer Tools opens in a new window when I press F12. It used to open in a panel at the bottom of the current IE8 window. The Pin button at the top right does nothing, neither does the Ctrl+P shortcut. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that I had hit F5 to reload a page I was working on, but since I had the Developer Tools open and pinned, F5 instead behaved as a shortcut to "Start Debugging". To allow the Pin button to work, I had to click the "Stop Debugging" button under the Developer Tools Script tab.